# Фон блока на всю высоту экрана

Tags: css, background

Приветствую.

Как сделать так, чтобы с любого устройства начальный фон был под высоту экрана устройства как в [примере](https://makoframework.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополню ответ **user190134**. 
Если блок находится не в корне body то укажите ему `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Раньше работал с vh да и сейчас работаю, но никогда 100 не ставил.Теперь попробовал. Все работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно давать высоту 100%. Но помните, что высота в процентах берется от высоты родителя. Так что необходимо давать высоту html,body тоже в 100%

Comment: Хм.. Если position:relative то свойство height работать не будет. Оно зависит от наполнения (контента). Тогда нужно использовать absolute позиционирование?